# Uploading image to ASP.NET site with avalible content-type

Tags: asp.net, content-type

I currently have a web service set up to upload and save a file (.png image) to my website using the following code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string SaveDocument(byte[] docbinaryarray, string docname)
{
    string strdocPath;
    string docDirPath = Server.MapPath("\\") + uploadDir;
    strdocPath = docDirPath + docname;
    if (!Directory.Exists(docDirPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(docDirPath);
    FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(strdocPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    objfilestream.Write(docbinaryarray, 0, docbinaryarray.Length);
    objfilestream.Close();
    return "http:\\\\example.com\\" + uploadDir + docname;    
}
```

This code works fine, however when I access the image via the url I am not getting a content type that matches the png file (image/png). Is it possible to associate the content type when you upload a file so that when you visit the url (example.com/myimage.png) it returns the image with the image/png content type? Or do I need to somehow dynamically create webpages with the content type that link to these links?

**EDIT:**
The goal is to use this with a 3rd party API that needs to do a GET request and needs  to know the content-type, right now it specifies as invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Even though the content type header was set, the file was not being read as an image, but only as a file. That being the case the 3rd party API I was using was not correctly reading it and complained about the content type. The fix ended up being chaning my method to the following:

```
[WebMethod]
        public string SaveImage(byte[] docbinaryarray, string docname)
        {
            string strdocPath;
            string docDirPath = Server.MapPath("/") + uploadDir;
            strdocPath = docDirPath + docname;
            if (!Directory.Exists(docDirPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(docDirPath);
            using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(docbinaryarray)))
            {
                image.Save(strdocPath, ImageFormat.Png);  // Or Png
            }
            return "http://example.com/" + uploadDir + docname;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that something is not configired well in a your web server that blocks files or you pass wrong file name to this web service method.

I tested it and wrote simple implementation and all worked well. ASP.NET page uploads image to web service, web service returns a URL to uploaded image, page displays the image through Image1 control.

My simple implementation:

**Default.aspx:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_OnClick" />
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
namespace TestAspNetWebApp
{
    using System.IO;
    using System;

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string appPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\uploads\\";

            if (!Directory.Exists(appPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath);

            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string savePath = appPath + Server.HtmlEncode(FileUpload1.FileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);

                using (var objfilestream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    var len = (int) objfilestream.Length;
                    var mybytearray = new Byte[len];
                    objfilestream.Read(mybytearray, 0, len);

                    var myservice = new WebService();
                    var fileurl = myservice.SaveDocument(mybytearray, FileUpload1.FileName);
                    Image1.ImageUrl = fileurl;
                }

                File.Delete(savePath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**WebService.asmx.cs:**

```
namespace TestAspNetWebApp
{
    using System.IO;
    using System.Web.Services;

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        private const string uploadDir = "uploads-websevice";

        [WebMethod]
        public string SaveDocument(byte[] docbinaryarray, string docname)
        {
            string strdocPath;

            string docDirPath = Server.MapPath("\\") + uploadDir + "\\";
            strdocPath = docDirPath + docname;

            if (!Directory.Exists(docDirPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(docDirPath);

            var objfilestream = new FileStream(strdocPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            objfilestream.Write(docbinaryarray, 0, docbinaryarray.Length);
            objfilestream.Close();

            return "http://localhost:57064/" + uploadDir + "/" + docname;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm uploading the file fine, and it displays as an image fine. The issue is that there is no content-type response header associated with the image, so I can't access it from an API that expects a content-type.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. From original post that wasn't clear. How are you trying to pull the image from server that it doesn't return the content-type. I tried from browser and from fiddler and all works good. Look at this screen to see the result http://i.imgur.com/2ta0JVR.png

Comment: I added another answer with example of code, try to check it please and add your code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Please add some example of your code to help you to define the problem and to solive it.

It seems that server returns all headers and also 'Content-type' as usual.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
      string uri = "http://chronicletwilio.azurewebsites.net/res/12345.png";
      byte[] data = client.DownloadData(uri);
      string contentType = client.ResponseHeaders["content-type"];
      // contentType is 'image/png'
}
```